# Sobre Snippets no VS Code

Tags: c, json, c++, visual-studio-code

olá, eu uso Visual Studio Code, sou iniciante na programação e queria uma ajuda para montar snippets no VS Code, eu queria criar snippets para as funções basicas da linguagem C, como printf e scanf, ja procurei por exetensões e não existe nenhuma que me agrade.

O problema esta sendo que quando eu monto o Snippet printf("$1\n", $0); gera conflito com a linguagem .json utilizada para criar o snippet, pois na hora que eu uso os parenteses para a função e o \n ele conflita com o .json e não consigo colocar o \n no final da string que a função recebe e nem as " não sei se é possível fazer o que quero, mas gostaria muito de deixar parecido com os snippets do Atom. Segue imagem do erro de conflito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `"` dentro de `"` tem sempre de ser com `\"`, que seria um dos problemas que tem no snippet com `printf`

Comment: obrigado, funcionou ^^